# problems with javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

i have a litle question, I'm working on filling a table in jsp with foreach, this is the code:

```
<c:forEach items="${empresaList}" var="empresa" >
    <tr>
        <td>${empresa.emp_rut}</td>
        <td>${empresa.com_id}</td>
        <td>${empresa.emp_nombre}</td>
        <td>${empresa.emp_direccion}</td>
        <td>${empresa.emp_telefono}</td>
        <td>${empresa.emp_celular}</td>
        <td>${empresa.emp_descripcion}</td>
        <td>${empresa.emp_email}</td>
        <td>${empresa.emp_web}</td>
        <td><input type='button' id=eliminar
                onclick='confirmar(${empresa.emp_rut})' value='Eliminar'></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

in the onclick i put a parameter which gives a value to a javascript function for delete the row but first asks for a confirmation. the problem is when i run the page, the function does not affect all the rows.  if I delete the parameter of
`function confirmar()` and change the onlick to this:
 `onclick='confirmar()'`
, it work's(obviously will not remove the row in the controller but display the message )
  my question is why is that? the first javascript code it's very simple.

```
function confirmar(id)
{
    var respuesta = confirm('¿Está seguro que desea eliminar  '+id+'?');
    if(respuesta)
    {
        location.href='Eliminar?id='+id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `${empresa.emp_rut}` a string or number ? If it is a string value then it has to be quoted while passing the value to javascript function. So your code should be:

```
......
........
........
<!-- not that I have added double quotes in passing parameter to Javascript function calling -->
<td><input type='button' id=eliminar onclick='confirmar("${empresa.emp_rut}")' value='Eliminar'></td>

......
.......
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Always *look at the JavaScript* if you don't know what the JavaScript doesn't work. You are only looking at the JSP.

Most likely, `${empresa.emp_rut}` contains something like `foo` (which gives you an undefined variable called `foo`) or `foo bar` which is just a syntax error.

You need to quote your JavaScript string literals (and escape special characters within the string).